# Html page for displaying video in mobile

Tags: php, html, ffmpeg, html5-video

I am developing php pages for mobile, in one page i have to display video, 
now i am testing the php page in google chrome, but in Google chrome not playing mp4,avi,etc. chrome playing only ogg and ogv format.

I heard about ffmpeg, i installed in my Ubuntu 12.4 environment, 
but it is also not converting to videos to ogg and ogv fromat.
it converting other format like mp4,avi,ect.

**Displaying video using**

```
 <video width="320" height="240" controls="controls" autoplay="true">
  <source src="/SeeSayDo/<?php echo $model->av;?>" />
</video>
```

user may uploads any video format like avi,mp4,flv,etc, so i have to display any format they uploaded.

Comment: https://github.com/etianen/html5media

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be trying to play an AVI in a web browser ever. The formats that you should use in the HTML5 video tag are H.264 and Ogg/Theora (and maybe WebM), and that will get you the most coverage of supported browsers (see http://caniuse.com/#search=video for supported browsers/formats).

You will have to [detect](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/) the browser and/or [device](http://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/) and choose the proper video format.

[Read this](http://deepbluesky.com/blog/-/quick-tip-converting-video-to-ogg-webm-and-other-html5-formats_138/) for help converting your videos.

Comment: i have suggested to use ffmpeg, do you have any idea about that ?

Comment: yeah. ffmpeg is hard to use if you aren't familiar with the command line arguments or video compression algorithms in general. The article I referenced suggested a GUI video converter http://www.mirovideoconverter.com/ that looks pretty sweet. there is also handbrake (http://handbrake.fr/)

Comment: I missed the part about needing to encode on the fly, where ffmpeg is a good idea. here's a great guide: http://paulrouget.com/e/converttohtml5video/

Comment: can you explain what is mean encode on the fly, also i tried to convert mp4 video to ogg format using the command (ffmpeg -i foo.mp4 foo.ogg) but, it is not working.

Comment: by encode on the fly, i mean you need your server to re-encode the videos that are uploaded automatically, and therefore you need a command-line interface you can install on your server rather than a GUI. You may need to follow that guide i referenced step by step starting with compiling ffmpeg. If you don't compile with the right settings, it can't encode what you need.